# Change color on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I generate a `ggplot` by:

```
 x <- rnorm( 10^3, mean=0, sd=1)
 y <- rnorm( 10^3, mean=0, sd=1)
 z=x^2+y^2
 df <- data.frame(x,y,z)
 ggplot(df)+geom_point(aes(x,y,color=z))
```

By default, this is plotted on a blue scale. How can I combine different colors to make a new scale?

Comment: `+ scale_colour_gradient(low='white', high='orange')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an almost limitless number of ways to set colors in `ggplot`, so many in fact that it can get confusing. Here are a couple of examples to get you started. See documentation [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_gradient.html), [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_gradientn.html), and [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_gradient2.html) many more options. IMO [this site](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_%28ggplot2%29/) gives an excellent overview of color options in `ggplot`.

As @rawr points out in the comment, the options all involve some version of `scale_color_`

`scale_color_gradient(...)` associates colors with low and high values of the color scale variable and interpolates between them.

```
ggp <- ggplot(df)+geom_point(aes(x,y,color=z))
ggp + scale_color_gradient(low="red", high="blue")
```

[image]

`scale_color_gradientn(...)` takes a color palette as argument (e.g., a vector of colors) and interpolates between those. Color palettes can be defined manually or using one of the many tools in R. For example, the `RColorBrewer` package provides access to the color schemes on [www.colorbrewer.org](http://www.colorbrewer.org).

```
library(RColorBrewer)   # for brewer.pal(...)
ggp + scale_color_gradientn(colours=rev(brewer.pal(9,"YlOrRd")))
```

[image]

```
library(colorRamps)     # for matlab.like(...)
ggp + scale_color_gradientn(colours=matlab.like(10))
```

[image]

`scale_color_gradient2(...)` produces a divergent color scale,  designed for data that has a natural midpoint (your example doesn't...).

```
ggp +
scale_color_gradient2(low="blue",mid="green",high="red",midpoint=5,limits=c(0,10))
```

[image]

This really just scratches the surface. For example, there is another set of tools in `ggplot` to deal with discrete color scales.